Windows refuses to open any more files after opening a certain number of files and keeping them all open
I am doing some AI work and, as a result, manually open up multiple images and tools. I've noticed that after I open a certain number of files, Windows simply refuses to open any more programs or files (of any type). When I double-click on something in Explorer, nothing happens - even no error messages are shown. However, it stays fully responsive and the Task Manager shows plenty of resources still free. New files can only be opened if I close existing ones. And this happens every time I open a certain number of files/programs.
I am wondering why this is the case and if there are ways to circumvent this. Thanks for any help.
OS: Windows 11 Pro 24H2 x64
CPU: Ryzen 5 3600 (6c/12t)
Memory: 2 x 16GB DDR4-3200
Disk: OS - NVMe SSD (Kingston A2000), Work drive - SATA SSD (Samsung 870 EVO)




look at the Handles, you have 267850 handles being opened which is far below the limit. It's not quite a lot of of threads either. Try opening Windows Event Viewer and Resource Monitor to see

You might experiment with changing virtual memory (https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-virtual-memory-size-windows-10) and using ISLC, https://www.wagnardsoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1256&sid=3e139188e47dfc79d1035dcd47e3f3c0
